# How to find symbol name for Binance websocket API

Tags: binance

in [DOCS](https://docs.binance.org/api-reference/dex-api/ws-streams.html#8-individual-symbol-ticker-streams) we see:

```
const conn = new WebSocket("wss://dex.binance.org/api/ws");
conn.onopen = function(evt) {
    conn.send(JSON.stringify({ method: "subscribe", topic: "kline_1h", symbols: ["BNB_BTCB-1DE"] }));
}
```

But my question is how to find out that symbol name `BNB_BTCB-1DE`, especially what does the last suffix part `B-1DE` means? What could be complete symbol names to get kline data for btcusd, or ethusd ? Does that suffixes change dynamically, or from where we can get those list.

Comment: Are you aware that you are in the Binance DEX API, not the main Binance.com API?  They will have different symbols.  All DEX symbols: https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/markets, all main exchange symbols: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo

Comment: @NickFriskel can you tell (give link) where i find what are differences of DEX (or what is that at all?) than main Bin-Api?  thanks!!

Comment: The main Binance exchange is found at https://www.binance.com, this is a normal cryptocurrency spot exchange where you can deposit and trade coins and Binance holds and manages your funds.  Binance has now came out with their own Decentralized Exchange (DEX), which is completely separate from the main exchange.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_exchange

Answer (score 3):

As far as i have found out, there is no endpoint from which which to download ALL symbol FULL names.

515 symbols currently (June 2022) have `assetName` available on the [exchangeInfo public endpoint](https://www.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo), as either a `baseAsset`or a `quoteAsset`.

158 of these have their `assetFullName` available on the private endpoint `/sapi/v1/margin/allAssets`.